# How to format AJAX POST request vs cURL?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I'm sending a POST request cia cURL and when parsing it in my Java server, it's fine.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url":"http://example.com"}' http://example-server.com/pathtoserver

I'm grabbing the request in Java via:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line);
}

String data = buffer.toString();

if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("Data grabbed for POST data: " + data);
}
```

The log statement is:

```
2014-09-29 16:29:19,153 [INFO] [pool-16-thread-16] LOG - Data grabbed for POST data: {"url":"http:example.com"}
```

But when I send it via a JQUERY AJAX request, I get a JSONException error. Am I formatting the request wrong?

```
$('#validate').click(function() {
    alert($('#url').val());
    console.log($('#url').val());
    $.ajax(
        {url: "/pathtoserver/",
         type: "POST",
         data: {url:$('#url').val()},
         success: function(data) { handleValidateResponse(data); console.log(data); }
        });
    });
```

The log also states:

```
2014-09-29 16:27:08,145 [INFO] [pool-16-thread-14] LOG - Data grabbed for POST data: url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

The URL is now encoded, plus instead of a JSON object with curly braces ( {url:...} ) like the first one, it says "url=..."

Is there something inherently different about cURL vs AJAX post requests? Or am I formatting something wrong?

Comment: Do you read from GET? You are surely sending a POST request with AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually stringify your object to JSON. jQuery will convert your object to a string of key/value pairs otherwise. I would also add `contentType: "application/json"` just for safe measure:

```
$.ajax(
    {url: "/pathtoserver/",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: JSON.stringify({url:$('#url').val()}),
     success: function(data) { handleValidateResponse(data); console.log(data); }
    });
```